# Is there a faster way in Rails to determine if all objects in an array contain a couple of attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.  I have a group of objects, stored in an array called results.  Each object has some attributes.  I want to know if all objects contain a couple of attributes, so I use

```
  has_all_numeric_attr_data = results && results.all?{|r| r.numeric_attr && r.numeric_attr > 0}
  has_all_string_attr_data = results && results.all?{|r| r.string_attr.present? }
```

This works fine, however, it is somewhat slow if the array contains large numbers of objects, in as far as I'm iterating over the array twice.  Is there a way to get the same data but only iterating over the array once?

Comment: do you need to know which attribute is not present? or just need to know if one/both of them are not present?

Comment: I need to have two varaibles -- one will tell me if one attribute is present in all the data and the other will tell me if the other attribute is present in all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest, but you can set both variables to `true` and then loop the array, changing the value of the variables if the condition is met, for example:

```
has_all_numeric_attr_data = true
has_all_string_attr_data  = true

results.each do |r|  
  has_all_numeric_attr_data = false unless r.try(:numeric_attr) && r.numeric_attr > 0
  has_all_string_attr_data  = false unless r.try(:string_attr).present?
end
```

Only one loop is needed.

---

You can further optimize the code by exiting the loop whenever both conditions are met (i.e. both `has_all_numeric_attr_data` and `has_all_string_attr_data` have been set to `false`):

```
results.each do |r|  
  break unless has_all_numeric_attr_data || has_all_string_attr_data

  has_all_numeric_attr_data = false unless r.try(:numeric_attr) && r.numeric_attr > 0
  has_all_string_attr_data  = false unless r.try(:string_attr).try(:present?)
end
```

Comment: This is fundamentally different htan what I asked though.  In my quesiton it is possible to have "has_all_numeric_attr_data" be true but "has_all_string_attr_data" be false.  In your answer, they would eitehr be both true or both false, si taht right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I thought that was the desired behavior. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this logic but written in a more succinct manner, it's a single iteration.

```
def check(results)
  numeric_c = 0
  string_c = 0
  results.each do |r|
    numeric_c+=1 if r.numeric_attr && r.numeric_attr > 0
    string_c+=1 if r.string_attr.present?
  end
  return { all_numeric: numeric_c==results.count, all_string: string_c==results.count }
end
```

This will return:

```
{:all_numeric=>true, :all_string=>false} #(e.g)
```

So you can have:

```
checked = check(results)
has_all_numeric_attr_data = checked[:all_numeric]
has_all_string_attr_data = checked[:all_string]
```

And you can easily add the number of occurrences wtv. And add an early return in case results is empty.